# Python Lists/ Tuples in terms of sorting

Tags: python, sorting, tuples

I am struggling to overcome a problem/task in Python and I'm really stuck for ideas. I need to read two lines from a file, sort one of these lines (from multiple files which are determined from user inputted data) but return both pieces of data in the context of a running club. The users average miles per hour will be calculated over a few weeks and stored in a .txt file alongside a user id stored at the beginning of the program, the final section of the program will need to read these files (the user id and the average miles per hour) and sort the average miles per hour while keeping the user id (returns both together allowing for a summary). I then need to state the top few runners. Any help would be much appreciated and I have not used SQL etc, just line-by-line, standard Python. My code is un-optimized but I'm at 'the home straight' with it now. Also, my friend suggested for me to use tuples but I don't know where to start in all honesty. Please excuse any 'elementary mistakes'. I have also played with tuples but never properly integrated them as I don't know where to begin. Also finding problems with the saving of variables as the clash with the operators which means I cannot globalize them without defining each and everyone.

```
    def retrieve():
global datasave,y ###don't know where to go from this as it does not work
y=1
if y>3: #just practiced with 2 'users'
    y=str(y) 
    print("All members entered and saved, a comparision of average miles per hour will be intiated")
    file=open(y+".txt",'r') #saves files in which they occur for easy 'read'
    datasave=file.readline(5)
    datasave,y=datasave #gave me a 'cannot assign to operator' error
    y=int(y)
    y=y+1
else:
    avmphlist=[datasave1,datasave2,datasave3,datasave4,datasave5,datasave6,datasave7,datasave8,datasave9,datasave10]
    sorted(avmphlist)
    print(avmphlist)
    print("Unfortunately ",avmphlist[9]," and ",avmphlist[10],"have not made the team, thank you for your participation")
    print("Congratulations to ",avmphlist[1],", ",avmphlist[2],", ",avmphlist[3],", ",avmphlist[4],", ",avmphlist[5],", ",avmphlist[6],", ",avmphlist[7]," and ",avmphlist[8],)
```

Comment: Your title is extremely vague and misleading.

Comment: The entire question is extremely vague... Where is your code? What have you tried? What exactly didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start with defining a list of tuples for you data

```
runnerData = [("TestName1", 70),("TestName2", 50), ("TestName3", 60)]
```

now use the inbuild sort method:

```
sortedRunnerData = sorted(runnerData, key=lambda data: data[1])
```

Now you have a sorted list of tuples of your data (ascending). If you need it in descending order just reverse the list:

```
sortedRunnerData.reverse()
```

Now the list sortedRunnerData list contains the data in descending order.